# Get highest resolution on images / vectors

Tags: java, android, vector

In my app there are plenty of images/icons. When running it on my phone, their **resolutions** are okay, but not as high-quality as the ones on professional apps.

**My question**: What is the best way to import images/icons to Android Studio?

I'm currently importing **SVG** vector format icons using **VectorAsset** tool, and calling them from the XML with `app:srcCompat = "@drawable/whatever"`

[ScreenShot from Android Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NM9wi.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Android Drawable Importer is one of the best way to import images of big resolutions with different image resolution types in Android.

Download the plugin
Open Android studio. Go to File>Settings>Plugins>Browse Repositories.
Search for “Android Drawable Importer” in the search box

Follow this link and use it -
https://medium.com/code-yoga/create-drawables-from-a-large-scale-image-automatically-2128dde61ad9

For icons you can add images as vector image assets.  Follow this -

https://www.dev2qa.com/how-to-add-images-in-android-studio-drawable-folder/